# Socket.IO only works locally

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have this Node.JS **server**:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = app.listen(80);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var posx = 10;
var posy = 10;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile( __dirname + '/index.html' );
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('start', {
        x: posx,
        y: posy
    });

    socket.on('newpos', function (data) {
        posx = data["x"];
        posy = data["y"];
        socket.broadcast.emit('move', { x: posx, y: posy });
    });
});
```

**CLIENT SIDE CODE:**

```
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');

            socket.on('start', function (data) {
                $("#pointer").animate({
                    'top': data["y"],
                    'left': data["x"]
                }, 0);
            });

            socket.on('move', function (data) {
                $("#pointer").animate({
                    'top': data["y"],
                    'left': data["x"]
                }, "slow");
            });

            $("#pointer").draggable({
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    var pos = $("#pointer").position();

                    socket.emit('newpos', {
                        'x': pos.left,
                        'y': pos.top
                    });
                }
            });
```

The problem is that it seems to be only working locally.
On ubuntu chrome I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/socket.io/1/?t=1344711676473. Origin http://192.168.1.130 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

While on a mac, I am having a GET error for the same file...

Any idea on what the problem might be?

Comment: What's your client-side code?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A site's domain doesn't have to do with where it is hosted, it has to do with what URL you are using to access it.

Even if "192.168.1.130" and "localhost" resolve to the same server, they are considered different domains.

As a result, because you have the client side code:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
```

You are connecting to the *domain* localhost.  If the client code was served by localhost you're fine, but if you are loading the client from another domain (for example 192.168.1.130) then you'll face problems.  From the browser and server's perspective you could easily be a complete stranger trying to access that service.

To fix the problem change the client side socket creation to:

`var socket = io.connect('192.168.1.130');`

You should have your problem resolved.

Really though, you should just remove the parameter completely and try running:

`var socket = io.connect();`

That way it will default to whatever domain you are based on, and it will work both on localhost, the IP, and eventually the domain name you use.

Comment: oh boy... sooo stupid!!! totally forgot about that... my question is worth a delete shah

Comment: No it's an easy mistake to make!  The question will help others facing similar problems.

Comment: What if I need to specify a port number with var socket = io.connect(); how would you do that?

Comment: Agreed, very easy mistake to make. On Socket.io 1.x I simply needed to use: `var socket = io();` No need for .connect();

Comment: I'm glad you didn't delete this, came in very handy and now I'll probably never forget it. ;)

Comment: Especially since the official tutorial mentions adding the `localhost` part :/

Answer (score 2):

Change the app.listen(80) to app.listen(80, '192.168.1.130') for it to use that IP, that way your URLs from socket.io should be correct. Also be sure to access it from 192.168.1.130 in your browser even if you try it on the local machine.

Comment: no luck.. still the same error. also I don't think it'd be a good idea to put the local IP as I would like my server to be accessible from outside my intranet.