# Socket.io not connecting to local host server

Tags: android, sockets, socket.io

[I am doing everything as per this to connect localhost to app using socket.io .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916999/socket-io-only-works-locally)

but it is not connecting, i have connected my phone and laptop to my phone's network. I don't know where i am going in wrong direction. Please guide me.

**I have this node server :**

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mysql = require('mysql');


var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    port : "3306",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "socket_database",
    charset : 'utf8mb4_bin',
    multipleStatements: true
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    let sender = socket.handshake.query.user_id;
    console.log('a user connected with id - '+ sender);

.
.
.

}

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
})
```

**Android Side Code :**

```
private var mSocket: Socket? = null


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        try {

            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.40.28:3000")

            mSocket?.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, Emitter.Listener {
                Log.d("TAG", "Socket Connected!")

            })
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println(e.localizedMessage)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `http://192.168.40.28:3000` is it your laptop IP or your mobile device?

Comment: I have connected my mobile's network to laptop via hotspot. and ip i have fetched form laptop settings -> Wifi -> My phone's network -> IP Setting and Properties

Comment: and if i run ipconfig in cmd, i am getting same ip address, @kdblue

Comment: did you hit this IP in your pc?

Comment: @kdblue, means ?

Comment: did you hit this ip http://192.168.40.28:3000? in your pc !

Comment: @kdblue, i have pinged it in cmd. if that is what you mean by hit...

Comment: i mean in your browser

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47125117/6925888 , see this maybe its help you!

Comment: @kdblue, yeah , i have done it and it runs my index.html

Comment: do you get any error in the android side? check the logcat!

Comment: @kdblue  no, not getting any error , that's why i can not detect the problem

Comment: then debug the app !

Comment: @kdblue already done it. it does not go in error block. just when you debug it shows socket.connection() to false. no any other information. and that's frustrating...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199417/discussion-between-kdblue-and-zephyr).